# PHP ODBC_FETCH_INTO returns null for large nvarchar

Tags: php, odbc

I'm storing data in SQLServer 2008 using PHP.

The data type is nVarChar(Max).

Very large strings post and save correctly, however when I odbc_fetch_into, the values longer than 4104 characters place a null value in the array.

I can select left([Note], 4104) and it will return the left 4101 characters, but when I select left([Note], 4105), it places null into the array.

Is there something I need to do to my PHP array to make it accept larger values?
Or perhaps fetch the fields separately?

```
$SQL = "SELECT left([Note],4104) FROM [myTable] WHERE [myKey] = myVariable"; //Works for all strings!
//$SQL = "SELECT [Note] FROM [myTable] WHERE [myKey] = myVariable"; //Works for strings <= 4104 characters

$row = array();
$stuff = array();

$prep = odbc_prepare($conn, $SQL);
$ret = @odbc_execute($prep);

while (odbc_fetch_into($prep,$row)) {
    array_push($stuff,$row);
}

echo json_encode($stuff);
```

UPDATE: I just did a var_dump on $stuff, and come to find out it has a lot of garbage after character #4104. In Firefox, lots of diamond/question-mark characters, along with remnants of the PHP source and previously-returned results.

Comment: Another update: odbc_fetch_row along with odbc_result yield the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have a partial answer anyhow...

there's a parameter in PHP.ini called odbc.defaultlrl. That value will limit the return size of an odbc field.

Still not sure why all the gabage was there at the end. When I changed the field value from nvarchar(max) to varchar(max) or text, the garbage disappeared but the size limitation was still there.

My php.ini was set to 4096 - not sure how I was getting 4104 bytes out of it.